# c++ unordered_set .find method won't compile, gives "expression must have class type" error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, find, unordered-set

So, I'm trying to write a function that can determine how many strings in a collection are anagrams of other strings in that collection. To do this quickly, I've elected to sort the strings, and then move them into a "
valid" and "invalid" hash set, depending on whether I've found a duplicate. Trouble is, When I try to use the find method for unordered_sets, I get a compile time error that tells me "expression must have class type".

I've looked around the website, but I didn't see any posts with that error that I recognized as being the same problem.

I'm working in visual studio, in c++, and I should mention that the code is not finished; I haven't written anything after the line that's giving me the error. Also, it is specifically the name of the std::unordered_set "valid" that is underlined in red.

It is also worth noting that this code is a work-in-progress, so there are a few things written down that I may not actually need; for example, I probably won't end up using those long longs (because I've realized that trying to use a single, enormous character array rather than strings is probably more effort than it's worth.)

Here is the method I'm working on:

Edit: I removed some of the irrelevant parts of this method due to sensitivities concerning it's origin. I apologize for my lack of foresight.

```
int Anagram_Locator::filterAnagrams()
{
    ...

    //the valid and invalid hash sets
    std::unordered_set<std::string> valid();
    std::unordered_set<std::string> invalid();
    //pull in the words, and sort them. Then, send them to either the valid or invalid string hash sets
    while (std::cin >> transferString)
    {

        ...

        //is it in the valid list?
        std::unordered_set<std::string>::const_iterator found = valid.find (transferString);

    }
}
```

The last line in this code snippet is the one that is not compliling. This is particularly frustrating to me, because it is written exactly as it was in this c++ guide:

[The c++ reference page I was looking at](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/find/)

I would think that this is all the code I would need, but experience has taught me that programming problems often have causes in parts of the code that I think are irrelevant. As such, I have posted the rest of my code below.

Edit: the rest of the code turned out to be irrelevant, so I removed it for clarity.

Comment: Your code suffers from [the most vexing parse in C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). `valid` is not an object of type `std::unoredered_set<std::string>`. It is a function that takes no arguments and returns a `std::unoredered_set<std::string>`. `invalid` is also such a function.

Comment: You might consider putting all of this in one file and removing anything that isn't necessary to cause the issue. In doing so you may actually find the problem or at least narrow it down. This is called a [mcve] and is very helpful in getting others to actually look at your code. The story method with the code strewn all over the place, not so much.

Comment: All right, I will remove extraneous information... which, in this case, is almost all of it. (Apologies for that, by the way; I'm still a new programmer, so I'm still not great at determining what is and is not relevant.

Comment: @RSahu -- this is **not** the "most vexing parse". It's simply a function declaration. The "most vexing parse" is more subtle. The Wikipedia article you link to gives examples; this is not one of them.

Comment: @PeteBecker, it is the simplest form of the most vexing parse. It declares a function while intention was to construct an object using the default constructor.

Comment: @RSahu -- that makes "most vexing parse" so broad that it's not a useful term. As I said, the wikipedia article that you cited does not claim that `T x();` is an example. That's because `T x();` is useful when used according to its meaning. The examples of the term "most vexing parse" are constructs that, regardless of whether you intended to create an object or a function declaration, are better rewritten. "Most vexing parse" is a style error. `T x();` is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears incorrect:

```
std::unordered_set<std::string> valid();
std::unordered_set<std::string> invalid();
```

You are declaring two functions that return sets, not two sets.

Don't you really want:

```
std::unordered_set<std::string> valid;
std::unordered_set<std::string> invalid;
```

Comment: ...That's probably it. Let me check real quick.

Comment: Yep, that was it. It's always the little things. Thanks.

Comment: don't forget to accept the answer  (or upvote it, or both), if you found it useful.